# Add bevel effect to UIView

Tags: ios, uiview, bevelled

I want my button to look this.

[image]

I asked the designer and he said he has used bevel effect on it and I'm hearing the word bevel for the first time.

I searched Stack Overflow but couldn't find anything helpful.

Comment: For understanding bevel effect - http://www.rw-designer.com/bevel-effect-explained

Comment: still can't find anything on how to do this in iOS

Comment: The tutorial explain here how to add bevel/emboss effect to the image https://blog.jayway.com/2017/03/12/realistic-text-emboss-effect-in-ios/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bevel is a "sloping surface along the edge of a piece of wood, glass etc". In the computing world we use a "bevel" typically around a button, to give the illusion of 3D. Although there's been a definite trend since iOS7 to prefer a flatter look.

When you say you wish to apply a bevel to a UI view, you're referring to the gradient around the edge. I've highlighted this in red, in the image below.

[image: Highlighted bevel]

When you say you want your button to look like your image, the bevel might only be part of that goal.

As has already been suggested, the quickest and easiest way to make your button look like that, would be to use an image of the button, and apply this to your view. This is probably more efficient way of doing it too. Alternatively, it is possible to create the button using code. Although you would need the button in a vector format.

In order generate the button in code, you would need to ask your designer for the button in a vector format. The SVG format would probably be easiest. There are a number of third party programs that can convert vector images to Core Graphics code. For this example, I've used a program called Graphic (by Autodesk). Although, I had to fix a couple of bugs in its generated code. A more up to date alternative may be better. I've not tried Graphic to generate code in Swift.

Here's my example of a button, which is similar to your design. This code is a proof of concept, so the button isn't sized or positioned very well. I've not spent too long matching my button to your exact design. However, it will produce a view with a similar button in it.

```
#import "Button.h"
#import <CoreText/CoreText.h>

@implementation Button

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    // enable the following lines for flipped coordinate systems
    //CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, 0, self.bounds.size.height);
    //CGContextScaleCTM(ctx, 1, -1);
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

    /*  Shape   */
    CGMutablePathRef pathRef = CGPathCreateMutable();
    CGPathMoveToPoint(pathRef, NULL, 251.424, 272.035);
    CGPathAddCurveToPoint(pathRef, NULL, 251.424, 288.189, 238.328, 301.285, 222.174, 301.285);
    CGPathAddCurveToPoint(pathRef, NULL, 206.02, 301.285, 192.924, 288.189, 192.924, 272.035);
    CGPathAddCurveToPoint(pathRef, NULL, 192.924, 255.881, 206.02, 242.785, 222.174, 242.785);
    CGPathAddCurveToPoint(pathRef, NULL, 238.328, 242.785, 251.424, 255.881, 251.424, 272.035);
    CGPathCloseSubpath(pathRef);

    /*  Gradient Fill  */
    CGContextSaveGState(ctx);
    CGContextAddPath(ctx, pathRef);
    CGContextClip(ctx);

    CGFloat gradientColors[] = {
        0.549, 0.557, 0.565, 1,
        0, 0, 0, 1 };
    CGFloat gradientLocations[] = { 0, 0.973 };

    CGGradientRef gradientRef = CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents(colorSpace, gradientColors, gradientLocations, 2);
    CGContextDrawLinearGradient(ctx, gradientRef, CGPointMake(201.492, 251.353), CGPointMake(242.857, 292.719), (kCGGradientDrawsBeforeStartLocation | kCGGradientDrawsAfterEndLocation));
    CGGradientRelease(gradientRef);
    CGContextRestoreGState(ctx);

    CGPathRelease(pathRef);

    /*  Shape 2  */
    CGMutablePathRef pathRef2 = CGPathCreateMutable();
    CGPathMoveToPoint(pathRef2, NULL, 247.069, 272.035);
    CGPathAddCurveToPoint(pathRef2, NULL, 247.069, 285.784, 235.923, 296.93, 222.174, 296.93);
    CGPathAddCurveToPoint(pathRef2, NULL, 208.425, 296.93, 197.279, 285.784, 197.279, 272.035);
    CGPathAddCurveToPoint(pathRef2, NULL, 197.279, 258.286, 208.425, 247.14, 222.174, 247.14);
    CGPathAddCurveToPoint(pathRef2, NULL, 235.923, 247.14, 247.069, 258.286, 247.069, 272.035);
    CGPathCloseSubpath(pathRef2);

    /*  Gradient Fill  */
    CGContextSaveGState(ctx);
    CGContextAddPath(ctx, pathRef2);
    CGContextClip(ctx);

    CGFloat gradientColors2[] = {
        0.165, 0.153, 0.153, 1,
        0, 0, 0, 0.651 };
    CGFloat gradientLocations2[] = { 0.897, 0.991 };

    CGGradientRef gradientRef2 = CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents(colorSpace, gradientColors2, gradientLocations2, 2);
    CGContextDrawRadialGradient(ctx, gradientRef2, CGPointMake(222.174, 272.035), 0, CGPointMake(222.174, 272.035), 24.895, (kCGGradientDrawsBeforeStartLocation | kCGGradientDrawsAfterEndLocation));
    CGGradientRelease(gradientRef2);
    CGContextRestoreGState(ctx);

    CGPathRelease(pathRef2);

    /*  Text   */
    UIColor *colour = [UIColor colorWithRed:1 green:1 blue:1 alpha:1];
    NSMutableAttributedString *attributedStr = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"STOP"];
    NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
    paragraphStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
    NSDictionary *textAttribs = @{
                                  NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:10],
                                  NSForegroundColorAttributeName: colour,
                                  NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyle
                                  };
    [attributedStr setAttributes:textAttribs range:NSMakeRange(0, 4)];


    CGRect textBox = CGRectMake(208.736, 270.375, 28.051, 14);
    CGPathRef textBoxPath = CGPathCreateWithRect(CGRectMake(0, 0, textBox.size.width, textBox.size.height), NULL);
    CTFramesetterRef framesetter = CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString((__bridge CFAttributedStringRef)attributedStr);
    CTFrameRef frameRef = CTFramesetterCreateFrame(framesetter, CFRangeMake(0, 0), textBoxPath, NULL);
    CGContextSaveGState(ctx);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, textBox.origin.x, textBox.origin.y);

    CGContextSetTextMatrix(ctx, CGAffineTransformIdentity);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, 0.0, textBox.size.height);
    CGContextScaleCTM(ctx, 1.0, -1.0);
    CTFrameDraw(frameRef, ctx);

    CGContextRestoreGState(ctx);
    CGPathRelease(textBoxPath);
    CFRelease(framesetter);
    CFRelease(frameRef);

    /*  Shape 3  */
    CGMutablePathRef pathRef3 = CGPathCreateMutable();
    CGPathMoveToPoint(pathRef3, NULL, 229.861, 260.812);
    CGPathAddCurveToPoint(pathRef3, NULL, 229.861, 262.987, 228.098, 264.75, 225.923, 264.75);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathRef3, NULL, 218.423, 264.75);
    CGPathAddCurveToPoint(pathRef3, NULL, 216.248, 264.75, 214.485, 262.987, 214.485, 260.812);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathRef3, NULL, 214.485, 260.812);
    CGPathAddCurveToPoint(pathRef3, NULL, 214.485, 258.637, 216.248, 256.874, 218.423, 256.874);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathRef3, NULL, 225.923, 256.874);
    CGPathAddCurveToPoint(pathRef3, NULL, 228.099, 256.875, 229.861, 258.638, 229.861, 260.812);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathRef3, NULL, 229.861, 260.812);
    CGPathCloseSubpath(pathRef3);

    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(ctx, 0.514, 0.773, 0.357, 1);
    CGContextAddPath(ctx, pathRef3);
    CGContextFillPath(ctx);

    CGPathRelease(pathRef3);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

}


@end
```

[image: Screenshot of the result in the iOS simulator]

Answer (score 3):

I believe that the designer meant bevel and emboss effect. Here is a sample extension on UIImage for applying an emboss effect with a shader image.

```
extension UIImage {
    func applyBevelAndEmboss(shadingImage: UIImage) -> UIImage {
        // Create filters
        guard let heightMapFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIHeightFieldFromMask") else { return self }
        guard let shadedMaterialFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIShadedMaterial") else { return self }
        // Filters chain
        heightMapFilter.setValue(CIImage(image: self),
                                 forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
        guard let heightMapFilterOutput = heightMapFilter.outputImage else { return self }
        shadedMaterialFilter.setValue(heightMapFilterOutput,
                                      forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
        shadedMaterialFilter.setValue(CIImage(image: shadingImage),
                                      forKey: "inputShadingImage")
        // Catch output
        guard let filteredImage = shadedMaterialFilter.outputImage else { return self }
        return UIImage(ciImage: filteredImage)
    }
}
```

Do ask the designer for the shader image and to apply on the flat image.

My personal opinion is that, it is better to get the processed image from the designer and use it rather than performing all that processing in the app.

Answer (score 0):

My proposal is to export this button (without text) in vector if possible. And you it simply as image. Sometimes it's better to save your time and use images in such cases. I prefer to draw simple shapes only. Or you can achieve this by replacing bevel effect with combination of gradient / border / shadow.